# Finding the nearest shop to a house

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and am trying to solve the following problem.

For every house, I want to find the shop closest to it. The house and shop coordinates are given in a list. Here is a sample test case:

```
House=[3, 7, 15, 19, 37, 49, 51]
Shop=[1, 9, 16, 18, 67, 79, 47, 48]
Output {3: 1, 7: 9, 15: 16, 19: 18, 37: 47, 49: 48, 51: 48}.
```

I have written a solution using two `for` loops, but I'm required to produce a solution with a time complexity better than `O(n**2)`. The code I have is as follows:

```py
def locator(house,n_h,shop,n_s):
    loc=[]
    loc_temp=[]
    dict1={}
    indx=0
    for i in range(n_h):
        for j in range(0,n_s):
            loc_temp.append(abs(house[i]-shop[j]))
        indx=loc_temp.index(min(loc_temp))
        loc_temp.clear()
        loc.append(shop[indx])
        dict1[house[i]]=loc.pop()
    return dict1

house = [3, 7, 15, 19, 37, 49, 51]
n_h=len(house)
shop = [1, 9, 16, 18, 67, 79, 47, 48]
n_s=len(shop)
res=locator(house,n_h,shop,n_s)
print(res)
```

Is there a way to solve it faster (i.e. with a better asymptotic time complexity)?

Comment: Not enough info: what format are those coordinates in - 1D, 2D or 3D?

Comment: The coordinates are in 1D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the coordinates are in 1D, you could sort the array and then use the algorithm (which I don't know the name of) where you first look in the middle and if it's smaller you go in the first half and if it is bigger you go in the second half. 
This however would only be more efficient if this is going to be huge array, else your way should be *fine*.

Comment: You mean binary search?

Comment: Even then the complexity will be O(n2).